# Error using.getInfo function within a function Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, error, date, function

I'm applying a function to map a calculation over a list of dates. In the old calculation I just manually entered each date and ran the code. As part of if that code I would use `.get('year).getInfo()` to obtain the year from a manually entered data.

```
var startDate = ee.Date('2016-10-01');
var endDate = ee.Date(startDate.advance(1,'month'));

var startyear = startDate.get('year').getInfo(); 
var endyear = startDate.get('year').getInfo();
```

I've tried do this again within my function

```
  var start = ee.Date(date);
  var end = ee.Date(date).advance(1,'month');
  var date_range = ee.DateRange(start,end);
  
  var startyear = start.get('year').getInfo(); 
  var endyear = start.start.get('year').getInfo();
```

But I'm getting the error `Unknown variable references: [].`

I'm guessing it's got something to do with the `.getInfo` function and client vs server side. However, to obtain year as an object for use, I need to use `.getInfo` to obtain it. Does anyone know any work arounds?

The link to my code is [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fmjw1280%2FReef_Stress_Exposure%3ADate%20Tests%2FDATE_LIST_TEST_DHW%20(copy))

Comment: Why do you need to get the years with `.getInfo()`?

Comment: I have another line code further down that uses the year, var startdate = ee.Date.fromYMD(startyear, 1, 1); I could only get that to read the year using .getInfo. Are there other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in this line:

```
var enddate = ee.Date.fromYMD(endyear + 1 , 1 , 1);
```

because `endyear` is an `ee.Number` if you don't use `.getInfo()` you can not call +1 on it. Instead you need to use the Earth Engine specific functions:

```
var enddate = ee.Date.fromYMD(endyear.add(1) , 1 , 1);
```

If you do this, you can just remove the `.getInfo()` calls.

Comment: Thanks I thought it might be something simple. Greatly appreciated.